# What error should be thrown for impossible conditions?

Tags: java, exception

```
public static double findLCM (int num1, int num2) {

        for (int i = 1; i <= num2; i++) {
            double mult = big * i;
            if (mult % small == 0) {
                return mult;
            }
        }
        throw new Error("Error");
    }
```

As we know, it is impossible to not have an LCM. Please dont suggest me workarounds for the code like return variable after breaking from for loop etc. This code is custom made to understand the exception to be thrown.

Comment: You can create your custom exceptions:
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-custom-exception-example/

Comment: *"This code is custom made to understand the exception to be thrown."* You are actually throwing an Error which is not an Exception.

Comment: IllegalStateException?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest fit may be an [IllegalArgumentException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html):

> Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or inappropriate argument.

Comment: In this specific case I would agree with you; there is an argument that can be passed to the constructor that would trigger the error being thrown (i.e. `num2 < 1`.  But in cases where checks have been put in place against that, or there are language constructs that have to be violated for this section of code to be reached, `IllegalStateException` is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Exception

You can say:

```
throw new Exception("Error");
```

This will solve you problem. I am not 100 % sure but it worked for me many times.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a high-ranking search result, I felt the need to add a response.  @UnknownJoe left a comment on the question that, in my opinion, should be the correct answer for the general case, while @manouti's answer (accepted) is the correct answer for the specific case.

If there is any chance that a section of code could be accessed during the execution of the program due to invalid arguments being passed to the method, then `IllegalArgumentException` is the correct exception to throw; after all, it was an illegal argument that led to that code being executed.  In the example provided, if I passed a `0` in as the second argument, I'd have the exception thrown.

My personal use case for this was with `MessageDigest` algorithms. Since a known set of algorithms has been provided [since Java 1.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/CryptoSpec.html#AppA), I can feel free to directly reference any of these by name and not worry about the potential `NoSuchAlgorithmException`.  While I could swallow the exception, wrapping it in an `IllegalStateException` allows me to pass it up the chain if my code's being run on a non-standard implementation, or if something's very wrong with the environment; more importantly, however, I'll know why my program is failing.

So in short: if your code can be accessed accidentally by providing invalid arguments, use `InvalidArgumentException`.  If your code cannot be accessed normally and only by a fluke of the JVM, use `IllegalStateException`.